# FORALL+ EXECUTE IMMEDIATE + INSERT Into tbl SELECT

Tags: oracle, forall

I have got stuck in below and getting syntax error - Please help.
Basically I am using a collection to store few department ids and then would like to use these department ids as a filter condition while inserting data into emp table in FORALL statement.

Below is sample code:
while compiling this code i am getting error, my requirement is to use INSERT INTO table select * from table and cannot avoid it so please suggest.

```
create or replace Procedure abc(dblink VARCHAR2)
 CURSOR dept_id is select dept_ids from dept;
 TYPE nt_dept_detail IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(25);
 l_dept_array nt_dept_detail;
Begin
 OPEN dept_id;
 FETCH dept_id BULK COLLECT INTO l_dept_array;
 IF l_dept_array.COUNT() > 0 THEN

    FORALL i IN 1..l_dept_array.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO stg_emp SELECT
      Dept,''DEPT_10'' FROM dept_emp'||dblink||' WHERE
      dept_id = '||l_dept_array(i)||'';      
      COMMIT;
 END IF;
 CLOSE dept_id;
 end abc;
```

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the error is, or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: How difficult is it to copy paste your session details including the error stack. Just execute it in SQL*Plus and copy paste the content.

Comment: If you get a message like 'compiled with warnings' or 'see compiler log', in some clients you can use the `show errors` to see the actual problems; and you can query the `user_errors` view from any client.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you bothering to use cursors, arrays etc in the first place? Why can't you just do a simple insert as select?

Problems with your procedure as listed above:

1. You don't declare procedures like `Procedure abc ()` - for a standalone procedure, you would do `create or replace procedure abc as`, or in a package: `procedure abc is`
2. You reference a variable called "dblink" that isn't declared anywhere.
3. You didn't put `end abc;` at the end of your procedure (I hope that was just a mis-c&p?)
4. You're effectively doing a simple insert as select, but you're way over-complicating it, plus you're making your code less performant.
5. You've not listed the column names that you're trying to insert into; if stg_emp has more than two columns or ends up having columns added, your code is going to fail.

---

Assuming your dblink name isn't known until runtime, then here's something that would do what you're after:

```
create Procedure abc (dblink in varchar2)
is
begin
  execute immediate 'insert into stg_emp select dept, ''DEPT_10'' from dept_emp@'||dblink||
                    ' where  dept_id in (select dept_ids from dept)';
  commit;
end abc;
/
```

If, however, you do know the dblink name, then you'd just get rid of the execute immediate and do:

```
create Procedure abc (dblink in varchar2)
is
begin
  insert into stg_emp -- best to list the column names you're inserting into here
  select dept, 'DEPT_10'
  from dept_emp@dblink
  where  dept_id in (select dept_ids from dept);
  commit;
end abc;
/
```

Comment: Also reference to `l_l_dept_array` in the `FORALL`, instead of `l_dept_array`.

Comment: Thanks...i just pasted sample code...all is ok except that execute immediate and insert where i am getting compilation error.

Comment: When you post sample code, it helps us to help you if you post code that accurately reproduces the issues you're seeing. We can't see your screen! You need to provide much more (accurate!) information if you want us to help you. For example, "compilation error"? What message, exactly?

Comment: I can see you've corrected your original procedure, but you still haven't amended the "l_l_dept_array" to "l_dept_array" issue which Alex mentioned above. Also, when you pass in the dblink name, is it prepended with @? If not, you're either going to have to add it at the beginning of the variable, or you're going to have to add it after the tablename. (e.g.: '...from table_name@'||dblink||' where ...')

Answer (score 1):

There appears te be a lot wrong with this code.
1) why the execute immediate? Is there any explicit requirement for that? No, than don't use it
2) where is the dblink variable declared?
3) as Boneist already stated, why not a simple subselect in the insert statement?
INSERT INTO stg_emp SELECT
      Dept,'DEPT_10' FROM dept_emp@dblink WHERE
      dept_id in (select dept_ids from dept );

For one, it would make the code actually readable ;)

Comment: If (a big if!) the dblink variable is actually a variable and not known at runtime, then dynamic sql is the only way to go. If it is known, then I agree, totally no need for dynamic sql!

Comment: db link would be known at runtime so i have to use dynamic SQL

Comment: That's a good reason then. But still, you can use the query I wrote down and get the same results. There is hardly no performance penalty in using dynamic sql, but you should avoid it for the Obvious readability and code maintenance reasons.<br>